# Bxslider: content and next/prev arrows fade when slides fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, bxslider

My controls fade out every time the BX slideshow transitions, as does any content that overlays the slideshow, even if it's not within the wrapper that's being used for slideshow initiation. This issue does not happen in 'horizontal' mode, just 'fade' mode. I'm using custom next and prev arrows like this:

```
<div class="bx-controls-direction is-select-disabled">
    <span class="bx-direction prev bx-prev"><< Custom Arrow</span><span class="bx-direction next bx-next">Custom Arrow >></span>
</div>
```

And using this code to make them functional (it also resets the timer):

```
       $('.bx-next').click(function(e){
            slider.stopAuto();
            slider.goToNextSlide();
            slider.startAuto();
        });

        $('.bx-prev').click(function(e){
            slider.stopAuto();
            slider.goToPrevSlide();
            slider.startAuto();
        });
```

Please see this working fiddle for a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/pRBVZ/

Is this a bug, or is there an issue with my code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added a css property and it seems to have solved your problem.

Try replacing the follwoing class

```
.bx-controls-direction {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   width: 100%;
   z-index:100;
}
```

You have given z-index:55 to your content and I believe that is interfering with your controls.

Comment: Great find Vijeta. Somehow I missed that one. I actually increased the z-index on .bx-direction, but same idea. Accepted!